# C++ iterating map

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl

As known the following code is used to iterate map in C++

```
for (std::map<char,int>::iterator it=mymap.begin(); it!=mymap.end(); ++it)
{
    std::cout << itr->first << " => " << itr->second << '\n';
}
```

Where **itr** is declared as **std::map::iterator**. The members first and second are declared neither in [std::map](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) nor in [std::iterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator). Then how is it available for access?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The elements of an [`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) are `std::pair<key_type, mapped_type>`, so de-referencing a map iterator gives you a reference to one of these.

It is the [`std::pair`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair) class template which has `first` and `second` members.

Answer (score 2):

The basic idea behind iterators is that they are "magical" objects used to access data, that behave like pointers do on an array - i.e. you use arithmetic operators (e.g. `++` and `--`) to move around and you dereference (using `*` and `->`) to access the data.

So, `itr` is "like" a pointer to an `std::pair<char, int>`, so you can access the data dereferencing it via the `*` operator (which yields the key/value `pair`) or with the `->` operator, as in your example.