# Does map initialize its mapped type when it is an array of ints and it is created by operator[]

Tags: c++, arrays, insert, initialization, stdmap

Can I rely on the compilers behaviour in this case?

Lets assume I have a `std::map`...

```
std::map<int, int[10]> _map;
```

... and later on I perform...

```
++(_map[5][0]);
```

... and 5 is a new value for the map

Am I going to have 0 in the 0th element of the array before performing the incrementation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ iterating map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22061866/c-iterating-map)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd have a 1 in the 0th element of the array.

When `_map[5]` is called, the int array associated with 5 is created, and initialized with a default value of 0 for each element, before being returned as a reference. Then you access index 0, and increment it with `++`, so the value will be set to 1.

Think of it like this:

```
auto& arr = _map[5];//Array created and initialized, because of behavior of std::map::operator[]
int & i = arr[0];
++i;
```

Which is identical code to what you wrote.

Comment: Sorry, I ment before access it for incrementation, according to std::map' s operator [] its mapped_type value will be value-initialized, but can I surely rely that it is applicable for arrays

Comment: @NikolayDobrev It is applicable. Value-initialization for arrays means having each element set to 0, or the default value otherwise if it's an object type.